# onClick launches Activity incorrectly (in 2.3.6)

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an interface that provides a set of multiple `Button` objects, each of which has attached the same `OnClickListener`. When said `Button`s are clicked, they should launch an `Activity`, as specified in `onClick`.

Here is my code for reference:

```
public class Calcs extends SherlockFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        CalcLoader buttonListener = new CalcLoader(getActivity());
        LinearLayout buttons = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.calculatorlist); // v is the inflated View
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View b = buttons.getChildAt(i);
            if (b instanceof Button) {
                ((Button) b).setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
            }
        }

        // Test Code: Location 1
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyCalcActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(i);

        // ...
    }

    private class CalcLoader implements OnClickListener {
        private Activity mOwner;

        public CalcLoader(Activity owner) {
            mOwner = owner;

            // Test Code: Location 2
            Intent i = new Intent(mOwner, MyCalcActivity.class);
            mOwner.startActivity(i);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v instanceof Button) {
                // Actual Code: Location 3
                Intent i = new Intent(mOwner, MyCalcActivity.class);
                mOwner.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite this, however, I'm getting some odd behavior. In the above code, I've placed some `startActivity` tests, labelled locations 1 and 2. In both cases, the `Activity` launches correctly, and all is well!

However, at location 3, where the working code should execute, I get some strange behavior from the launched `Activity`:

- At first, the `Activity` is launched just fine. It displays a single text field and it is focused, with the soft keyboard coming up. This is correct.
- Now, when I click the back button, the keyboard closes. This is correct.
- Click back again, and the field loses focus. This should NOT happen. Instead, the `Activity` SHOULD close and return to the previous one.
- Click back again, and the entire app closes (instead of returning to the previous `Activity`). Obviously, this should NOT happen.

To reiterate, when the `Activity` is started from location 1 or 2, everything functions correctly; the back stack is correct and returns to the initial `Activity` properly.

What is going wrong here? Why, when I start my `Activity` from `onClick`, does it fail, while it works from any other location?

**Update:** Saving the `Intent` in the constructor and reusing it in the `onClick` method produces the same glitched result, as does starting the `Activity` from the UI thread.

**Second update:** Making the text field unfocusable had no effect on the glitch; the back button still closed the app. Additionally, running in the 2.3.3 emulator had the same result. Oddly, though, after the second back button press (the text field losing focus), if you wait ~3 seconds, the `Activity` closes and returns to the main one.

**Third update:** No key events (`onKeyDown` or `onBackPressed`) are fired for the back button that takes focus from the text field. Additionally, if you interact with the `Activity` after the text field loses focus, it shows the animation of loading a new `Activity` of the same type, but the glitch is present here as well.

This appears to be an OS-level issue, found in Android 2.2 (API 8), 2.3.1 (API 9), and 2.3.3 (API 10). Eclair (API 7), and APIs 11+ do not have this issue. At this point, I believe I'm looking for some kind of workaround...

Comment: Well written question +1

Comment: did you try to manually set the focus to something else? or to set focusable=false in the text field?

Comment: If I set `android:focusable="false"`, the `Activity` loads without the `EditText` having focus. However, I hit back once, and nothing happens; hit back a second time, and the app closes.

Comment: Could be a bug on HTC's end... have you tried testing Android 2.3 using the emulator? Or even 2.2, etc?

Comment: Just ran it in the emulator on 2.3.3; same result as the Nexus One.

Comment: Just discovered something. If I hit back (close keyboard), and back (remove focus from field), then wait 3 seconds, it returns to the main `Activity`. This is just getting odder and odder...

Comment: Umm... I have no idea if this is what is causing the problem... but you can't be sure that the `Activity` will be created in `onCreateView`. You are only guaranteed that the `Fragment` is attached and the `Activity` has been created in `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: Also "location 1" looks like it will *always* launch a new activity when you first start up this particular `Fragment`? Is this true? Why exactly are you doing that in the first place...?

Comment: (Grr, I hate that "chat" button. <_<) Location 1 and Location 2 are just test codes to ensure that the `Activity` CAN be launched properly. Location 3 is the only code that will execute in the final product.

Comment: My last addendum before I sleep on this problem... if I switch orientation (once only) while in the `Activity`, then hit back, everything works fine, and works fine for all successive launches of the `Activity` until the main `Activity`'s tab is changed (and presumably, the launched `Activity` is purged from memory). What might happen in an orientation change that would allow the `Activity` to function normally?

Comment: Unless you are catching and dealing with the orientation change yourself, an orientation change will destroy (after calling `onSaveInstanceState()`) and recreate the activity that is the top of the stack (thereby calling `onCreate()`, `onRestoreInstanceState()`, etc.)

Comment: Then this definitely has to be an OS glitch, wouldn't you agree? I don't handle orientation changes, so I think this is some weird anomaly where the `Activity` is unable to close properly. (`onStop` isn't even called...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was not caused by something I detailed in my original post, so I apologize for that.

The issue was caused by a `SurfaceView` item on a tab unrelated to the tab I was testing on. After rebuilding the tabs and layouts from the ground up (and building each time), I discovered the lag-back-glitch was only caused when a `SurfaceView` was present in a non-focused tab.

I finally found that [I was not the only one with this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356085/android-viewpager-surfaceview-long-delay-when-navigating-back-to-activity).

To solve:

- Created an `onPause` method in the main `Activity`. In here, I destroy the `SurfaceView` using `container.removeView(..);`.
- Created an `onResume` method in the main `Activity`. In here, I inflate the `SurfaceView` from a new XML file containing ONLY the `SurfaceView` item, and add it to the original `container`.
- Lastly, implemented a `android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback` in the `SurfaceView` to erase the contents of the surface before it is removed.

It stumps me that this happens only on APIs 8-10, but I'm glad it's solved now. Kudos to everyone that offered their assistance!