# SurfaceView with ViewPager in API level 10 has a long delay during a new transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a very similar question to: 
[ViewPager + SurfaceView = long delay when navigating back to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356085/android-viewpager-surfaceview-long-delay-when-navigating-back-to-activity)

Except that I am using API 10 and so I am not using fragments.

I have SurfaceViews in the ViewPager - and I have that working well, except that when I scroll to a new page, it takes a while to draw.  It is not until the SurfaceView is visible on screen that the SurfaceView.surfaceCreated method is called. I would like to have the surface created at the time that ViewPager's PagerAdapter.instantiateItem is called and the SurfaceView is added to the ViewPager via addView. Is there a way to force the SurfaceView to create a surface at that point?

I am using code based on the [Awesome Pager example](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java)

```
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            Log.i("Main Activity", "instantiateItem p:" + position);
            View p;
            if(position == 1){
                    // Page003 is a surfaceview
                p = new Page003(cxt, position);
            } else {
                    // in the future I will create more pages!
                p = new Page003(cxt, position);
            }
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(p);

            return p;
        }
```

Is there a method similar to the answer in the other question - by wrapping the SurfaceView in another view? I'd rather not complicate the code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Implement onAttached() in your Viewpager Adapter
Run an handler for 2 sec thats it

This will load your surface  after 2 sec no more lag